# Set textField.text from other class of my app

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitextfield

I am trying to solve my problem with searching in Developer Library but probably i dont know for what should i search.

I have HeadViewController.h where i set property of my IBOutlet textField.
In that view i have another view (containerView) with ContainerViewController class.

My **problem is that i cant set textField text in my HeadViewController** even if i try to set property of my HeadViewController class in my ContainerViewController.h

Here is what am i trying to:

ContainerViewController.h

```
@class HeadViewController;

@property HeadViewController *hvc;
```

ContainerViewController.m

```
#import "HeadViewController.h"

// in my IBAction method
self.hvc.textField.text = @"text from container view";
```

I also trying to use [textField setText:@""] and [textField inserText:@""] but with same result. If anyone know where is my problem or for what i have to search in Developer Library i will appreciate that.

Comment: is `self.hvc.textField` not nil at the time you are trying to set text?

Comment: That field is empty default at the time when i want to set text in it

Comment: I got that but can you check in the debugger whether is it a nil?

Comment: Yes is nil before and after my code also nil. Sorry for that time delay but i was not by the mac :)

Comment: so you need to initialise your textfield to be able to set text and this is your problem that you are trying to set a property on a uninitialised object, maybe you haven't connected outlet?

Comment: I check the connection with Storyboard and everything is ok. I also try initWithString but same result.

Comment: with provided info I can not help you further but at least you know why it is not working, you had to broke something so that it is not initialised

Comment: here is the link to video https://www.dropbox.com/s/4segu20pfo5eq86/String%20from%20other%20class.mov?dl=0

Comment: movie is great but I'm interested in code not the effect

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63549/discussion-between-mayo323-and-julian-krol).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the value of your property, hvc. hvc is a pointer, but just declaring it doesn't make it point to anything, it just says what class of object it should point to. Since ContainerViewController is embedded in a container in HeadViewController's view, that makes HeadViewController the parent. So you can reference HeadViewController from ContainerViewController by using self.parentViewController.

```
// in my IBAction method
self.hvc = (HeadViewController *)self.parentViewController;
self.hvc.textField.text = @"text from container view";
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works now :) Very well explained where was the problem. Vote up for your answer! Thanks again.